# What is a Multiple Root Tag Problem in Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, layout

I Am newly learning application development in android studio, and i don't have a great background in java, while i was learning about layout i faced an error indicating a multiple root tag error, here's ly code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">
 <TextView
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Hello Carl!"
     app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
     app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width ="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height ="fill_parent"
 android:orientation= "vertical">
 <Button android:id ="@+id/btnStart"
     android:layout_width ="270dp"
     android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
     android:text ="@+string/Start" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I solve this problem, and please mention if should I only use one type of layout at once?

Answer (score 3):

You can have only one root tag in your XML layout file.

Example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
...your main content...
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Move your `LinearLayout` where there is `...your main content...`